# Label sobrepuesto en un input checkbox html y CSS

Tags: html, css, webforms

El problema con respecto al boton de "Recordar" en un login:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden apreciar, el input redondeado se encuentra sobrepuesto con el label.
Quisiera agregarle una distancia, pero no he encontrado solucion.

Este es mi codigo:

HTML

```
        <div id="popup" class="overlay">
            <div id="popupBody">
                <a id="cerrar" href="#">&times;</a>
                <img src="https://xxxxxxxx.xxx/images/icon.png" alt="TechLogo" style="width:150px;height:150px;" class="center">
                <div class="popupContent">
                    <input type="user" placeholder="User">
                    <input type="passw" placeholder="Password">
                    <div class="popupHelp">
                       <input type="checkbox" id="Remember" value="Remember"><label for="Remember">Remember</label>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btnSubmit"> Log In</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#popup div.popupContent input {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
}


#popup div.popupHelp {
    position: relative;
}

#popup div.popupHelp label {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 40%;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 25px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#popup div.popupHelp label:after {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    content: "";
    height: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 12px;
}

#popup div.popupHelp input[type="checkbox"] {
    visibility: hidden;
    text-align: right;
  }

#popup div.popupHelp input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    background-color: #66bb6a;
    border-color: #66bb6a;
  }

#popup div.popupHelp input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

Soy nuevo como programador web, agradezco las respuestas constructivas!

Comment: Has probado utilizar float:left en el label y float:right en el checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

Te he realizado una pequeña modificación al css, es mejor aplicar estilos al botón con el `after` del `label`, ahora, para el check, agrágalo al content del `after` y lo posicionas, o crea un `before` del label y lo ubicas sobre el botón, creo que puedes con eso.

```css
#popup div.popupContent input {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
}


#popup div.popupHelp {
    position: relative;
}

#popup div.popupHelp label {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 25px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

#popup div.popupHelp label:after {
  content: "";
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#popup div.popupHelp input[type="checkbox"] {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

#popup div.popupHelp input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
    background-color: #66bb6a;
    border-color: #66bb6a;
  }

#popup div.popupHelp input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div id="popup" class="overlay">
  <div id="popupBody">
     <a id="cerrar" href="#">&times</a>
     <img src="https://xxxxxxxx.xxx/images/icon.png" alt="TechLogo" style="width:150px;height:150px;" class="center">
     <div class="popupContent">
        <input type="user" placeholder="User">
        <input type="passw" placeholder="Password">
        <div class="popupHelp">
          <input type="checkbox" id="Remember" value="Remember"><label for="Remember">Remember</label>
        </div>
        <button class="btnSubmit"> Log In</button>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```